# Equivalent to Javascript yield* in C# that delegates to another iterator?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

Javascript has a `yield*` that is used to delegate to another generator or iterable object, such that the following use case produce `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`:

```js
for (const n of func1(2, 5, 8)) console.log(n)

function* func1(...nrs) {
    for (const n of nrs) {
        yield* func2(n)
    }
}

function* func2(nr) {
    yield nr - 1
    yield nr
    yield nr + 1
}
```

**Question**: Is there already, or any plan to provide an equivalent feature to `yield*` in C#?

---

The only way that I figure out to do something equivalent in C# requires two loops in `func1` such as:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach(var n in func1(2, 5, 8)) Console.WriteLine(n);
}

static IEnumerable<int> func1(params int [] nrs) {
    foreach (var iter in nrs)
        foreach (var n in func2(iter))
            yield return n;
}
static IEnumerable<int> func2(int nr) {
    yield return nr - 1;
    yield return nr;
    yield return nr + 1;
}
```

Comment: C# have no concept of `yield from` like python, but have `yield return` that returns single value. This means that you need to create nested `foreach`

Comment: Nothing like this in C# and no plans to add it as far as I can see either.

Comment: Note: There was a feature request some time ago: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/378

Comment: An alternative is LINQ: `nrs.SelectMany(func2)`

Answer (score 2):

Whilst there is no equivalent to `yield*`, you could achieve the same in your example using [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany):

```
static IEnumerable<int> func1(params int[] nrs)
    => nrs.SelectMany(func2);
```

`SelectMany` also has deferred execution, as with `yield`.

Unfortunately, you couldn't combine this with another `yield` statement; you would need a `foreach` in that case:

```
static IEnumerable<int> func1(params int[] nrs)
{
    yield return 0; // Another yield
    foreach (var n in nrs.SelectMany(func2)) yield return n; // Loop now needed
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You have a typo in `yield 0`. It should be `yield return 0`

Comment: @MiguelGamboa Yes, well spotted.